# Appending multiple user inputs to a list

Tags: python

I would like to know how I can take multiple user inputs and append each input to a list. For example, the user is asked how many times they would like to send a message. If they specify 3, then they are presented with three inputs which are later appended to the list.

I have tried several different ways to do this however I only ever see the last input appended to the list rather than the multiple inputs.

```
List = []
total = (int(input('How many?: ')))
for _ in range(total):
    messages = input('> ')
List.append(messages)

print (List)
```

Comment: Please specify Python version since ain't very clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did great actually, just need to indent `List.append(messages)` to include it in the loop code, otherwise you'll be appending the last message only to the list or (in the worst scenario where total is 0) you'll get a *not defined error*.

```
List = []
total = (int(input('How many?: ')))
for _ in range(total):
    messages = input('> ')
    List.append(messages)

print (List)
```

Comment: Inside the loop, you want ``raw_input``, not ``input``.

Comment: @Ben: how do you know the OP is using Python 2?  The `print` syntax suggests 3.

Comment: @Ben No, I think this is Python 3.

Comment: I usually see Python 3 tags when it is.

Comment: Yes normally it should be tagged, but I'm still suspicious, when the OP answers the comment I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = input('How many?: ')
l = [raw_input('> ') for i in range(n)]
```

Comment: This isn't a very thorough answer. I suggest you read over [**how to answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) and expand it.

Comment: Not only is it not thorough, it doesn't work. This will spit a `TypeError` because you are trying to make a range from a string. It should be `int(input())` to convert it explicitly.

Comment: @AlexThornton Ben is on the asumption that the OP is working with Python2, his code works well on Python2 since `input` will only accept numerical input.

Comment: @PauloBu I know it is not conclusive, but I would have thought that the OP's explicit type conversion combined with how he used `print` is clue enough.